# Why carboxylic group gets protonated preferantially on carbonyl oxygen?

Tags: acid-base, carbonyl-compounds

When carboxylic group gets protonated, by strong acid, proton binds rather to carbonyl oxygen, then to hydroxyl. Is that really true? Or maybe it's a case of kinetic vs thermodynamic stability?

Comment: Are you asking about carboxylic acid or hydroxyketone? There's a significant difference.

Comment: carboxylic acid

Comment: I thought so, edited it. Next time write properly, to not give us additional work.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20289/more-acidic-protonated-carbonyl-or-protonated-hydroxyl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A productive mechanism involving addition to the acid will require activation of the carbonyl group (consider, for example, acid catalyzed esterification). That happens via protonation of the carbonyl, not the hydroxyl. The latter is not productive (unless your mechanism proceeds via an acylium ion). Since proton transfers are fast, you are accessing all of the protonated specifies, and whichever one reacts most quickly is the one you should consider for the mechanism.